# Powershell - How to add values to two extensionAttributes at the same time?

Tags: powershell

```
Set-ADUser $user -Add @{extensionAttribute1 = "Jeff"; extensionAttribute2 = "AlsoJeff"}
```

The above is resulting in only attribute 1 being updated not both?

Both attributes to be updated but only 1 is being updated. I have made sure both are clear in AD as I have not added a clear parameter yet.

**UPDATE**: just conduct two setaduser brings to the same outcome as I was originally trying.

Comment: Does it work if you use `-Replace @{...}` instead of `-Add @{...}`?